# Выборка параметров товара

Tags: javascript, reactjs

как сделать поиск `skuId` исходя из выборного параметра на reactJs:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    "skuBase": {
      "skus": [
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624954",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:7184208885"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624955",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:7184208885"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624956",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:7184208885"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624957",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:7184208885"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624958",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:7184208885"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624959",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:7184208885"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624960",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:7184208885"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624961",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:7184208886"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624962",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:7184208886"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624963",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:7184208886"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624964",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:7184208886"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624965",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:7184208886"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624966",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:7184208886"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624967",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:7184208886"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973587",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:7184208887"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973589",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:7184208887"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973585",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:7184208887"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973591",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:7184208887"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973593",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:7184208887"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973595",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:7184208887"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973597",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:7184208887"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624968",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:3255486308"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624969",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:3255486308"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624970",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:3255486308"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624971",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:3255486308"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624972",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:3255486308"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624973",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:3255486308"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624974",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:3255486308"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624975",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:3255486309"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624976",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:3255486309"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624977",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:3255486309"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624978",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:3255486309"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624979",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:3255486309"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624980",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:3255486309"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4164813624981",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:3255486309"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973586",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:1135022227"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973588",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:1135022227"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973584",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:1135022227"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973590",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:1135022227"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973592",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:1135022227"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973594",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:1135022227"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4222725973596",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:1135022227"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647350",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5963101515"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647362",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5963101515"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647338",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5963101515"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647374",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5963101515"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647386",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5963101515"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647398",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5963101515"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647410",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5963101515"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647346",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5840039906"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647358",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5840039906"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647334",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5840039906"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647370",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5840039906"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647382",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5840039906"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647394",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5840039906"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647406",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5840039906"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647351",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5963101516"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647363",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5963101516"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647339",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5963101516"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647375",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5963101516"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647387",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5963101516"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647399",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5963101516"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647411",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5963101516"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647347",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5937273695"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647359",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5937273695"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647335",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5937273695"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647371",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5937273695"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647383",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5937273695"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647395",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5937273695"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647407",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5937273695"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647356",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:618399174"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647368",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:618399174"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647344",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:618399174"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647380",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:618399174"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647392",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:618399174"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647404",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:618399174"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647416",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:618399174"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647357",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:618399175"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647369",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:618399175"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647345",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:618399175"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647381",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:618399175"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647393",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:618399175"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647405",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:618399175"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647417",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:618399175"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647352",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5963101517"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647364",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5963101517"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647340",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5963101517"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647376",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5963101517"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647388",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5963101517"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647400",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5963101517"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647412",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5963101517"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647353",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5963101518"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647365",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5963101518"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647341",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5963101518"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647377",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5963101518"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647389",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5963101518"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647401",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5963101518"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647413",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5963101518"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647354",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5963101519"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647366",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5963101519"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647342",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5963101519"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647378",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5963101519"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647390",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5963101519"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647402",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5963101519"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647414",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5963101519"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647348",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5937273696"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647360",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5937273696"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647336",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5937273696"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647372",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5937273696"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647384",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5937273696"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647396",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5937273696"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647408",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5937273696"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647349",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5937273697"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647361",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5937273697"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647337",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5937273697"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647373",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5937273697"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647385",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5937273697"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647397",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5937273697"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647409",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5937273697"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647355",
          "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:5963101520"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647367",
          "propPath": "20518:3242701;1627207:5963101520"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647343",
          "propPath": "20518:3241147;1627207:5963101520"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647379",
          "propPath": "20518:33263;1627207:5963101520"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647391",
          "propPath": "20518:33264;1627207:5963101520"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647403",
          "propPath": "20518:33265;1627207:5963101520"
        },
        {
          "skuId": "4436941647415",
          "propPath": "20518:669;1627207:5963101520"
        }
      ],
      "props": [
        {
          "pid": "20518",
          "name": "尺寸",
          "values": [
            {
              "vid": "3242700",
              "name": "25",
              "translate": "25"
            },
            {
              "vid": "3242701",
              "name": "26",
              "translate": "26"
            },
            {
              "vid": "3241147",
              "name": "27",
              "translate": "27"
            },
            {
              "vid": "33263",
              "name": "28",
              "translate": "28"
            },
            {
              "vid": "33264",
              "name": "29",
              "translate": "29"
            },
            {
              "vid": "33265",
              "name": "30",
              "translate": "30"
            },
            {
              "vid": "669",
              "name": "31",
              "translate": "31"
            }
          ],
          "translate": "размер"
        },
        {
          "pid": "1627207",
          "name": "颜色分类",
          "values": [
            {
              "vid": "7184208885",
              "name": "复古蓝（八分）春款",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/3039690011/O1CN01IYzpiL1Bx4vMJWLV4_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Винтажная голубая (восемь центов) весна"
            },
            {
              "vid": "7184208886",
              "name": "复古蓝（九分）春款",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/3039690011/O1CN019BwAVJ1Bx4vK2AkKl_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Урожай голубой (девять баллов) весна"
            },
            {
              "vid": "7184208887",
              "name": "复古蓝（长裤）春款",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/3039690011/O1CN01hdDAcC1Bx4vHkpOyj_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Урожай голубой (брюки) весна"
            },
            {
              "vid": "3255486308",
              "name": "黑色（八分）春款",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/3039690011/O1CN01DRrNXE1Bx4vIWsYwN_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Черная (восемь центов) весна"
            },
            {
              "vid": "3255486309",
              "name": "黑色（九分）春款",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i2/3039690011/O1CN01QgOZZ11Bx4vHkpKs3_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Черная (девять баллов) весна"
            },
            {
              "vid": "1135022227",
              "name": "黑色（长裤）春款",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/3039690011/O1CN01o8JjsV1Bx4vK2Cgyw_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Черные (брюки) весенние"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5963101515",
              "name": "复古蓝（八分）薄绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/3039690011/O1CN01ojHEJl1Bx4vbaCd9B_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Ретро синий (восемь баллов)"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5840039906",
              "name": "复古蓝（九分）薄绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/3039690011/O1CN01KFjMrk1Bx4vWngW2k_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Винтажный синий (девять очков) бархат"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5963101516",
              "name": "复古蓝（长裤）薄绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/3039690011/O1CN01QWMkZJ1Bx4vZvPjs7_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Винтаж синего (брюки) тонкого флиса"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5937273695",
              "name": "黑色（八分）薄绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/3039690011/O1CN01FgI3fp1Bx4vWneN0A_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Черный (восемь баллов) бархат"
            },
            {
              "vid": "618399174",
              "name": "黑色（九分）薄绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/3039690011/O1CN01kDDwod1Bx4vXmOH4d_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Черный (девять очков) бархат"
            },
            {
              "vid": "618399175",
              "name": "黑色（长裤）薄绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/3039690011/O1CN01VZXlb01Bx4vXmOsU8_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Черный (брюки)"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5963101517",
              "name": "复古蓝（八分）厚绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/3039690011/O1CN01vGhUCL1Bx4vaCq0lx_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Урожай голубой (восемь очков) толстый ворс"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5963101518",
              "name": "复古蓝（九分）厚绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/3039690011/O1CN01v7m8U31Bx4vaCp0Pz_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Винтажный синий (девять очков) толстый бархат"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5963101519",
              "name": "复古蓝（长裤）厚绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i4/3039690011/O1CN01DoUlwC1Bx4vXmOsVe_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Ретро синий (брюки) толстый бархат"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5937273696",
              "name": "黑色（八分）厚绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i2/3039690011/O1CN01pW2oQg1Bx4vWnhFo3_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Чёрный (восемь баллов) толстый ворс"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5937273697",
              "name": "黑色（九分）厚绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i2/3039690011/O1CN01JBcHE41Bx4vZia0Ng_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Чёрный (девять очков) толстый ворс"
            },
            {
              "vid": "5963101520",
              "name": "黑色（长裤）厚绒",
              "image": "//img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i1/3039690011/O1CN01LlnoJQ1Bx4vZiak5H_!!3039690011.jpg",
              "translate": "Чёрный (брюки) толстый ворс"
            }
          ],
          "translate": "Цвет"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  skuProps = (pid,vid) => {
    console.log(pid +':'+ vid)
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.skuBase.props)
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.skuBase.props.map((value, key) => {
          return (
            <div key={key}>
              <p>{value.translate}</p>
              <ul>
              {value.values.map((v,k) => {
                return (
                  <li onClick={() => this.skuProps(value.pid, v.vid)} key={k}>
                    {v.translate}
                  </li>
                )
              })}

              </ul>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

параметры могут быть разные цвет, размер, тип сети, емкость [вот здесь пример кода](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gdrred)

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
  "skuBase": {
    "skus": [
      {
        "skuId": "4164813624954",
        "propPath": "20518:3242700;1627207:7184208885"
      }
    ]
  }
}

const result = state.skuBase.skus.filter(item => item.propPath == "20518:3242700;1627207:7184208885");

console.log(result);

// result: Array ["4164813624954"]
```

Comment: как именно собирать `20518:3242700;1627207:7184208885` при `onClick` вот в чем проблема

Comment: Вам нужен готовый код или объяснить как сделать?

Comment: я уже разбирался с кодом, мне интересно увидеть другое решения, возможно ваш код будет более оптимизированный.